# Week numbers between two dates

Tags: oracle, week-number

I'm trying to get the week numbers between two dates.

For example, between dates 01/01/2016 and 29/02/2016 I should have

```
S01 S02 S03 S04 S05 S06 S07 S08
```

Is it possible? How can it be done?

Comment: Do you have a table containing all dates?

Comment: What are the week numbers; calendar weeks? ISO week numbers within the year? What does the S represent? Do you want full weeks in the range or any partial weeks too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 'S' || LPAD( LEVEL, 2, '0' )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2016-01-01' + ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 7 <= DATE '2016-02-29';
```

**Output**:

```
'S'||LPAD(LEVEL,2,'0')
----------------------
S01                    
S02                    
S03                    
S04                    
S05                    
S06                    
S07                    
S08                    
S09
```

**Update - with months & dates**:

*Note: changed bounds to highlight difference between week number and sequence number.*

```
WITH bounds AS (
  SELECT DATE '2016-03-01' AS lower_bound,
         DATE '2016-04-30' AS upper_bound
  FROM   DUAL
),
weeks AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS id,
         lower_bound + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 AS week_date
  FROM   bounds
  CONNECT BY lower_bound + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 <= upper_bound
)
SELECT 'S' || LPAD( id, 2, '0' ) AS id,
       'W' || TO_CHAR( week_date, 'WW' ) AS week,
       'M' || TO_CHAR( week_date, 'MM' ) AS month,
       week_date
FROM   weeks;
```

**Output**:

```
ID  WEEK MONTH WEEK_DATE
--- ---- ----- ---------
S01 W09  M03   01-MAR-16 
S02 W10  M03   08-MAR-16 
S03 W11  M03   15-MAR-16 
S04 W12  M03   22-MAR-16 
S05 W13  M03   29-MAR-16 
S06 W14  M04   05-APR-16 
S07 W15  M04   12-APR-16 
S08 W16  M04   19-APR-16 
S09 W17  M04   26-APR-16
```

Comment: It's EXACTLY that I wanted !! Thank you dude :D

Comment: You got it for months ?

Comment: M01, M02 you see ? Months be two dates.

Comment: I got this error on TOAD for Oracle :ORA-32033: crénelage de colonne non pris en charge

Comment: Perfect dude :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you want the calendar week numbers then you can use a similar hierarchical approach to MTO's answer:

```
select distinct 'S' || to_char(date '2016-01-01' + level -1, 'WW') as week_num
from dual
connect by level <= date '2016-02-29' - date '2016-01-01'
order by week_num;

WEE
---
S01
S02
S03
S04
S05
S06
S07
S08
S09
```

If you want ISO weeks then use IW instead of WW, but that makes the first week S53 (from last year).