# Convert a date with Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, format

I would like to convert a date with Oracle, from this format:

```
25/01/2016 (DD/MM/YYYY)
```

To this format:

```
2016-01-25 (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

Here is the request this is required for (from [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574509/266304)):

```
  WITH bounds AS (
      SELECT to_char(to_date('01/01/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS lower_bound,
             to_char(to_date('29/02/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS upper_bound
      FROM   DUAL
    ),
    weeks AS (
      SELECT LEVEL AS id,
             lower_bound + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 AS week_date
      FROM   bounds
      CONNECT BY lower_bound + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 <= upper_bound
    )
    SELECT 'W' || TO_CHAR( week_date, 'WW' ) AS week
    FROM   weeks;
```

This works:

```
to_date(to_char(to_date('".$dateDebut."','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Is it currently a DATE, or a string value? How are you querying/viewing it now? If it's a date are you relying on your NLS settings to format it?

Comment: It is a string value I suppose

Comment: You should only need `to_date('".$dateDebut."','DD/MM/YYYY')` - once you have converted the string to a data you do not need to convert the date to a differently formatted string and then back to a date a second time.

Comment: As an aside - I used `DATE '2016-02-06'` in the linked question as this is the format for ANSI date literals (i.e. directly creating a date rather than specifying a string and converting it to a date). You do not need to use this format if you have dates in another format.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `to_date()` and `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(to_date(col, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You should, however, be storing dates in the database using native date formats, rather than as strings.

You can also use string manipulation:

```
select substr(col, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(col, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(col, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only really trying to convert a string to a date; as you're using it in a query it needs to stay as a date, and an Oracle date has no intrinsic format (it has an internal representation you don't care about here).

Your proposed solution:

```
to_date(to_char(to_date('".$dateDebut."','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

is converting your string to a date using one format mask; then back to a string and back to a date again using a different format mask. This is redundant, you only need:

```
to_date('".$dateDebut."','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

So you query becomes:

```
WITH bounds AS (
  SELECT to_date(".$dateDebut.",'DD/MM/YYYY') AS lower_bound,
         to_date(".$dateFinis.",'DD/MM/YYYY') AS upper_bound
  FROM   DUAL
),
weeks AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS id,
         lower_bound + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 AS week_date
  FROM   bounds
  CONNECT BY lower_bound + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 <= upper_bound
)
SELECT 'W' || TO_CHAR( week_date, 'WW' ) AS week
FROM   weeks;
```

Embedding string values from your UI into a query is bad practice though, as it leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Look into bind variables to avoid this.